# Will assigning an uninitialized pointer to something that points to where the OS is stored break the computer or just crash it?

Tags: pointers, crash

For example, if I had a pointer that was uninitialized and (unknown to me) pointed to somewhere important in the operating system, will it just crash the computer or will it overwrite something in the hard drive, destroying the computer?

Answer (score 0):

It will cause a segfault (segmentation fault). You cannot write in areas of memory that do not belong to you. It would crash the program for security measures. You can try to write to address 1 to test it.